Exclude typescript file in checkmarx
I have intergrated checkmarx step in jenkins, below is stage for checkmarx.
now I want to exclude scanning of typescript file with .tsx extension, I tried adding .tsx in filter pattern but still checkmarx does not exclude it. could you please suggest the correct way to achieve it.
      stage('Static Code Analysis') {
          steps {
            step([$class: 'CxScanBuilder',
                    comment: '',
                    credentialsId: 'Checkmarx',
                    hideDebugLogs: true,
                    excludeFolders: '.helmignore, build, templates, javadocs, javadoc, dist, node_modules, .js, .env.development, .git, public, .env.local, .gitignore, ci_job.sh, Jenkinsfile, uat_frontend.yaml',
                    excludeOpenSourceFolders: '',
                    exclusionsSetting: '',
                    failBuildOnNewResults: false,
                    failBuildOnNewSeverity: 'MEDIUM',
                    fullScanCycle: 10,
                    teamPath: 'CxServer/Cigna/MCHI',
                    includeOpenSourceFolders: '',
                    osaArchiveIncludePatterns: '*.zip, *.war, *.ear, *.tgz',
                    incremental: true,
                    osaInstallBeforeScan: false,
                    preset: 'Cigna - High and Medium - Web',
                    projectName: "${getProjectKey()}-${determineRepoName()}-${getCheckmarxEnvironmentName()}",
                    sastEnabled: true,
                    serverUrl: 'https://cigna.checkmarx.net/',
                    sourceEncoding: '1',
                    vulnerabilityThresholdResult: 'FAILURE',
                    generatePdfReport: true,
                    scaReportFormat: 'PDF' ,
                    waitForResultsEnabled: true])
          }
       }

